# UDPAnySourceMulticastClient works only in Wi-fi?

Tags: windows-phone-7, udp, discovery

I am developing an application in which device discovery in a network is required. I am using UDPAnySourceMulticastClient in windows phone 7 for discovering desktop clients. Whenever I connect desktop to a D-link or wi-fi connector, I am able to discover desktop in my wp7.

But my problem arises when I connect desktop through ethernet to some network and connect wp7 to the same network that desktop is using I am not able to discover desktops(Even though I am sending message to the group). Is it UDPAnySourceMulticastClient works only if both are connected through wi-fi network?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP multicast is dependent upon the hardware used to make the network (routers, etc.) to rebroadcast the message to all other clients. While more complex scenarios are possible, it's unusual for multicast to be enabled for anything other than communications connected to the same wireless hub.

Comment: Then which are the various methods for discovering devices or desktop clients in windows phone 7?